# Order / Address is not syncing on MySql data base using Shopify API

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, shopify

Actually I am syncing some columns from my Shopify JSON like "order_name" "order_id" "customer_name"

```
$hora = substr($order["created_at"],11,5);

if($res == 0){
$insQry = "INSERT INTO tbl_orders
        SET
            order_id = '".$order['id']."',
            order_name = '".$order['name']."',
            client = '".$order['customer']['first_name'].' '.$order['customer']['last_name']."',
            payment_status = '".$order['financial_status']."',
            print_status = 1,
            highrisk = '".$highRisk."',
            validada = '".$validada."',
            date = '".$order["created_at"]."',
            time = '".$hora."',
            delivery_type = '".$order["shipping_lines"][0]['title']."'
```

But for some reason it is not syncing the Address...
I have tried 3 forms:

```
           *FIRST FORM:-
            address1 = '".$order['shipping_address']['address1']."'
            address2 = '".$order['shipping_address']['address2']."'

           *SECOND FORM:-
            address1 = '".$order["shipping_address"]['address1']."'
            address2 = '".$order["shipping_address"]['address2']."'

           *THIRD FORM:-
            address1 = '".$order["shipping_address"][1]['address1']."'
            address2 = '".$order["shipping_address"][8]['address2']."'
```

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use file_put_contents function on your php file and write your response json to file or you can convert and then you can read or check from that file.

Example:

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$file_name = 'order.json';

file_put_contents($file_name, $json);

And then you use this code to retrieve contents:

$file_name = 'order.json';

$data_array = json_decode(file_get_contents($file_name), 1);

And then you can print $data_array and get the array printed and use it as you want.